# When did the first black holes form?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, astrophysics, big-bang

How long after the big bang did the first black holes form? How can we determine the answer to this question?

Comment: Less than one second after the Big Bang. [Perhaps!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_black_hole)

Answer (score 1):

Could be primordial (first second or few seconds, due to density fluctuations) but the data doesn't support much of it, as we should then be seeing some of it. That reference in the comment by @Pela has the wiki for it, with a lengthy treatment. Some papers have appeared that the two that merged and that LIGO saw were primoridal BHs, because they were more massive than expected, and that maybe more of them form the majority of dark matter. Other papers have indicated they could not be more than 1% of dark matter, so probably still unlikely.

The other possibility is after the first stars/galaxies formed, and stars evolved and collapsed. That'd be maybe a few hundred million years after the BB. See the answer at this other site for the same question.  https://www.spaceanswers.com/q-and-a/get-in-touch/
Most counts of how many there should be has it that we should detect a few each year with LIGO, so far we've not detected much.